# How to precompile CGAL headers to speed up (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, cgal, precompiled-headers

I was launching one of the examples offered by CGAL on their [website](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html), and I realized that the compilation time is very high, so I saw that one possibility was to generate a .h file including all the headers that are being used and precompile them.

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_set_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_set_3/IO.h>
#include <CGAL/remove_outliers.h>
#include <CGAL/grid_simplify_point_set.h>
#include <CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h>
#include <CGAL/jet_estimate_normals.h>
#include <CGAL/mst_orient_normals.h>
#include <CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h>
#include <CGAL/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction.h>
#include <CGAL/Scale_space_surface_reconstruction_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Scale_space_reconstruction_3/Jet_smoother.h>
#include <CGAL/Scale_space_reconstruction_3/Advancing_front_mesher.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh.h>
```

And after creating the MyHeaders.h I try to compile it using:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -lCGAL -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lgmp -lmpfr -L/usr/local/include
```

But errors of many kinds are coming out. This example, as far as I know, uses CGAL, BOOST, GMP and MPFR.

Does someone know how can I solve this problem? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with CGAL 5.4

The errors:

```
/usr/local/include/CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h: In instantiation of ‘bool CGAL::poisson_surface_reconstruction_delaunay(PointInputIterator, PointInputIterator, PointMap, NormalMap, PolygonMesh&, double, double, double, double, Tag) [with PointInputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index> > >; PointMap = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >; NormalMap = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >; PolygonMesh = CGAL::Surface_mesh<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >; Tag = CGAL::Manifold_with_boundary_tag]’:
main.cpp:99:38:   required from here
/usr/local/include/CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h:105:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<CGAL::Epick>::compute_implicit_function()’
  105 |     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h:21,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:417:8: note: candidate: ‘template<class SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, class Visitor> bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, Visitor, double, double) [with SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d = SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d; Visitor = Visitor; Gt = CGAL::Epick]’
  417 |   bool compute_implicit_function(
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:417:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from main.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h:105:10: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
  105 |     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h:21,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:571:8: note: candidate: ‘template<class SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d> bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d, bool) [with SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d = SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d; Gt = CGAL::Epick]’
  571 |   bool compute_implicit_function(SparseLinearAlgebraTraits_d solver, bool smoother_hole_filling = false)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:571:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from main.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h:105:10: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
  105 |     if ( ! function.compute_implicit_function() )
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/basic.h:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian/Cartesian_base.h:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h: In instantiation of ‘void CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::internal_np::geom_traits_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::normal_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::point_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> > >]’:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h:285:5:   required from ‘void CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >]’
main.cpp:86:65:   required from here
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h:202:3: error: static assertion failed: Error: no SVD traits
  202 |   CGAL_static_assertion_msg(!(boost::is_same<SvdTraits,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h: In instantiation of ‘void CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> > > > >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_monge_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_fitting_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> >]’:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Scale_space_reconstruction_3/Jet_smoother.h:83:5:   required from ‘void CGAL::Scale_space_reconstruction_3::Jet_smoother<Geom_traits, ConcurrencyTag>::operator()(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> > > >; Geom_traits = CGAL::Epick; ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag]’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Scale_space_surface_reconstruction_3.h:180:39:   required from ‘void CGAL::Scale_space_surface_reconstruction_3<Geom_traits>::increase_scale(std::size_t, const Smoother&) [with Smoother = CGAL::Scale_space_reconstruction_3::Jet_smoother<CGAL::Epick>; Geom_traits = CGAL::Epick; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
main.cpp:136:98:   required from here
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h:202:3: error: static assertion failed: Error: no SVD traits
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:59,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/config.h:431,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/basic.h:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian/Cartesian_base.h:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:667:7: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::internal_np::geom_traits_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::normal_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::point_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> > >]::<lambda(const reference&)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index&, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::null_type> >}]’, declared using local type ‘CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::internal_np::geom_traits_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::normal_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::point_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> > >]::<lambda(const reference&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
  667 |       function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:667:7: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::internal_np::geom_traits_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::normal_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::point_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> > >]::<lambda(const reference&)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index&, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::null_type> >}]’, declared using local type ‘CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::internal_np::geom_traits_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::normal_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >, CGAL::internal_np::point_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> > >]::<lambda(const reference&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:667:7: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> > > > >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_monge_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_fitting_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> >]::<lambda(const reference&)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::null_type> >}]’, declared using local type ‘CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> > > > >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_monge_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_fitting_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> >]::<lambda(const reference&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_function.h:667:7: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> > > > >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_monge_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_fitting_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> >]::<lambda(const reference&)>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::null_type> >}]’, declared using local type ‘CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set(PointRange&, unsigned int, const NamedParameters&) [with ConcurrencyTag = CGAL::Sequential_tag; PointRange = CGAL::Iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>*, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, std::allocator<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> > > > >; NamedParameters = CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_monge_t, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<unsigned int, CGAL::internal_np::degree_fitting_t, CGAL::internal_np::No_property> >]::<lambda(const reference&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

**Edit**: Add CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(CGAL_V0)

set(Qt5_DIR "/opt/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/")
set(CGAL_DATA_DIR "/usr/include/CGAL")
set(CGAL_DO_NOT_WARN_ABOUT_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE TRUE)

find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

find_package(GMP REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "GMP Found: ${GMP_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "GMP Libs: ${GMP_LIBRARIES}")

find_package(MPFR REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "MPFR Found: ${MPFR_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "MPFR Libs: ${MPFR_LIBRARIES}")

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(STATUS "Eigen3 Found: ${EIGEN3_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "Eigen3 DIR: ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(CGAL_V0 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CGAL_V0 CGAL::CGAL CGAL::CGAL_Core ${MPFR_LIBRARIES} ${GMP_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Did the original example already show the same errors? What is this meaningless `-L/usr/local/include` doing at the end of your command line, is it a typo? `-lCGAL` shouldn't be there, CGAL is header-only now.

Comment: You should try compiling with cmake once, to see what useful stuff it adds to the command line. In this case, it wants the include path for Eigen3.

Comment: If I compile it using cmake I have no error but the time of compilation is too high. I will edit the original post with the code I use to compile using CMake @MarcGlisse

Comment: So I've changed de g++ compiler line to: `g++ -std=c++14 MyHeaders.h -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/include/eigen3 /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.so /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so` but I still have and error: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: en la función _start: (.text+0x24): referencia a main sin definir collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: The point of using cmake was to notice that it adds -I/usr/include/eigen3, not actually stick to it. But note that cmake can perfectly well handle precompiled headers: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_precompile_headers.html . It doesn't make sense to list *.so files when precompiling a header.